# Can I correct position data from a device suffering from the 4/6/19 roll-over problem?

Tags: geometry, gps

I work for a company that sells apparatus containing GPS receivers. Over the years a lot of this gear has been sold and deployed. A number of machines in the field contain GPS receivers that feature the [week number roll-over issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Week_Number_Rollover) (WNRO).

Replacing all GPS receivers is costly. Software updates are easier. The receivers however are black boxes to us so if we were to do anything about it with a software update it would have to be on the position data level, the lat-lon data that we read from the device.

I am thinking about using translation tables that map position data that would have been accurate some 19 years ago to position data that is accurate now. I imagine this is possible because the difference in location of satellites between now and 19 years ago would be known. On the other hand, I would think this may be hard because the correction would be different for different regions and  because we do not know what satellites the device is fixed to at any particular time.

Is this possible at all? Do these tables exist? Is there a reasonably accurate way of using data from a rolled-over device to determine ones position?

Comment: On a surveyor's forum I follow, they discussed this in the context of having to correct RINEX files before sending them off for post-processing. Maybe check out that site, https://rplstoday.com.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you. I did find discussions about RINEX but nothing specific on correcting GPS data. There are 139 pages with messages about RINEX and if I add terms, I get more (the search function is not very smart). I guess I could register and ask the question there.